# Key Error mulitindex dataftame pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe (called Errors) that look like this:

```
Code                         ID                Error1     Error 2
Time                                                                
2010-01-01 00:00:31.690    105278.0             None         5  
2010-01-01 00:00:32.000    105278.0             1           None   
2010-01-01 00:00:32.140    105278.0             3           None   
2010-01-01 00:00:32.350    105278.0             None         7   
2010-01-01 00:00:32.460    105278.0             None         1
```

I want to count different type of errors for each time stamp and save them in separate column:

```
 error_count =
 pd.get_dummies(errors.set_index('Time')).reset_index()
 error_count.columns = ['Time', 'machineID', 'error1', 'error2',
 'error3', 'error4', 'error5']

 # combine errors for a given machine in a given hour error_count = error_count.groupby(['machineID', 'datetime']).sum().reset_index()
```

I have two issue one is that:
When I run

```
pd.get_dummies(errors.set_index('Time')).reset_index()
```

I get the key error (KeyError: 'Time')

The second issue is that I don't know how many different code I will get in my errors ( Error1 and Error 2 ) so I am not sure how I can write

```
error_count.columns = ['Time', 'machineID', 'error1', 'error2',
 'error3', 'error4', 'error5']
```

to reflect that.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ the answer that you provided was exactly what I was looking for. I greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you'll observe, `Time` is *already* set to the index. You can verify this by querying `df.index.name` and it should return `Time`.

For your second query, you can set `Time` and `ID` to the index and then call `pd.get_dummies`. Note that the assumption here is that `Time` is already the first index column in your data. We'll add another one with `set_index(..., append=True)`.

```
# df = df.replace('None', np.nan) # optional step, if `None` is a string
df 

                               ID Error1 Error2
Time                                           
2010-01-01 00:00:31.690  105278.0    NaN      5
2010-01-01 00:00:32.000  105278.0      1    NaN
2010-01-01 00:00:32.140  105278.0      3    NaN
2010-01-01 00:00:32.350  105278.0    NaN      7
2010-01-01 00:00:32.460  105278.0    NaN      1
```

```
pd.get_dummies(
     df.set_index('ID', append=True), prefix='', prefix_sep='')\
  .add_prefix("Error")\
  .reset_index()

                      Time        ID  Error1  Error3  Error1  Error5  Error7
0  2010-01-01 00:00:31.690  105278.0       0       0       0       1       0
1  2010-01-01 00:00:32.000  105278.0       1       0       0       0       0
2  2010-01-01 00:00:32.140  105278.0       0       1       0       0       0
3  2010-01-01 00:00:32.350  105278.0       0       0       0       0       1
4  2010-01-01 00:00:32.460  105278.0       0       0       1       0       0
```